# All combinations assuming independence

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics

This may be a basic question.

Given an array of probabilities of length $n$, trying to create a vector of all $2^n$ combinations assuming independence between them, where either $p_i$ or $1-p_i$ is chosen in each combination.

Input (for $n=3$)

```
p={p1,p2,p3}
```

Output

```
out={p1*p2*p3,p1*p2*(1-p3),p1*(1-p2)*p3,p1*(1-p2)*(1-p3),(1-p1)*p2*p3,(1-p1)*p2*(1-p3),(1-p1)*(1-p2)*p3,(1-p1)*(1-p2)*(1-p3)}
```

Comment: The function `Tuples` is probably what you want:  `n = 3; out = # /. List -> Times & /@ Tuples[Table[{p[i], 1 - p[i]}, {i, n}]]`.

Comment: Or: `pT = Transpose[{p, 1 - p}];
Flatten[Outer[Times, Sequence @@ pT]]`. Some people despise `Sequence`. Me, I like him just fine. And mostly for the type of use shown here (converting a `List` to a, well, sequence).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ps=Times @@@ Tuples[Transpose[{#, 1 - #}]] &;
```

Usage example:

```
p={a,b,c,d}
ps@p
```

> {a b c d,a b c (1-d),a b (1-c) d,a b (1-c) (1-d),a (1-b) c d,a (1-b) c
>   (1-d),a (1-b) (1-c) d,a (1-b) (1-c) (1-d),(1-a) b c d,(1-a) b c
>   (1-d),(1-a) b (1-c) d,(1-a) b (1-c) (1-d),(1-a) (1-b) c d,(1-a) (1-b)
>   c (1-d),(1-a) (1-b) (1-c) d,(1-a) (1-b) (1-c) (1-d)}

Comment: @JimB - Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you want to define `p`:

```
p=.;
n = 3;
out = # /. List -> Times & /@ Tuples[Table[{p[i], 1 - p[i]}, {i, n}]]
(* {p[1] p[2] p[3], p[1] p[2] (1 - p[3]), p[1] (1 - p[2]) p[3], p[1] (1 - p[2]) (1 - p[3]), 
    (1 - p[1]) p[2] p[3], (1 - p[1]) p[2] (1 - p[3]), (1 - p[1]) (1 - p[2]) p[3],
    (1 - p[1]) (1 - p[2]) (1 - p[3])} *)
```

or

```
p=.;
n = 3;
p = Table[ToExpression["p" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}]
out = # /. List -> Times & /@ Tuples[Table[{p[[i]], 1 - p[[i]]}, {i, n}]] 
(* {p1 p2 p3, p1 p2 (1 - p3), p1 (1 - p2) p3, p1 (1 - p2) (1 - p3), (1 - p1) p2 p3,
   (1 - p1) p2 (1 - p3), (1 - p1) (1 - p2) p3, (1 - p1) (1 - p2) (1 - p3)} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
probs = PDF[ProductDistribution @@ Map[BernoulliDistribution] @ #] /@ 
    Tuples[{1, 0}, Length@#] &;

probs[{a, b, c, d}] // Column
```

[image]

Also

```
bmterms = Table[BooleanMinterms[{i}, #], {i, 2^Length@# - 1, 0, -1}] /.
    {And -> Times, Not -> (1 - # &)} &;

bmterms[{a, b, c, d}] == probs[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```